# Overriding a parent div class on a child element within that div with the same class

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

The title is pretty confusing I know... I have applied a opacity to a parent element. Within that element is a child div that needs to have a different opacity rather than having its parent value. Please see example - http://bootply.com/65163. The buttons need to be opacity:1; rather than its parents opacity:.7;

```
            .carousel-search {
                margin: 7% 0 20px -208px;
                position: absolute;
                z-index: 9;
                text-align: center;
                opacity:.7;
                filter:alpha(opacity=70);  // IE
                -moz-opacity:0.7;          // Firefox
                -khtml-opacity: 0.7;
                left: 50%;
            }
            .carousel-search > .btn-group {
                opacity:1;
            }
```

Comment: One way of doing it is to make the parent have a rgba colour, but wondered if there was another way forward?

Comment: _“The buttons need to be opacity:1; rather than its parents opacity:.7;”_ – that is not possible, because opacity works on an element and _all_ its content.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This could be done using RGBA. I do not know a better way, do it like this:

```
.carousel-search {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 7);
}
```

This will add an opacity ONLY to the parent element. The child element is not affected with this opacity. So now you just can leave the opacity for the child element as it was (`opacity: 1`)

More about rgba [HERE](http://css-tricks.com/rgba-browser-support/)

**Edit:** I found another way, this is more of a css hack, but it will work too. http://www.impressivewebs.com/css-opacity-that-doesnt-affect-child-elements/

Answer (score 1):

This will do your work:

```
.carousel-search > .btn-group {
    background: rgba(x,y,z,1); //a is value of opacity
    }
```

Also check it out. http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Properties/color/RGBA